# Using Dart functions inside HTML

Tags: html, dart

Is it possible to use Dart functions inside <script> tags or other places in the HTML file, but the function body will be inside the Dart source file?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for AngularDart.  There may also be other frameworks but AngularDart is produced by Google to be used by Google.

Comment: Thank you Randal

Comment: In my humble opinion, Angular Dart is a Google inner product-oriented to their internal needs, not more than that, it will be too risky these days to use it.

Comment: Google could stop supporting it tomorrow.  But remember, it is all liberally open-sourced, so if there's enough interest, a community will fork it and continue on.